# Not able to comprehend the recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int fun(int a[],int n)
{
  int x;
  if(n == 1)
    return a[0];
  else
    x = fun(a, n - 1);
  if(x > a[n - 1])
    return x;
  else
    return a[n - 1];
}
```

I am unable to understand the functioning of this recursion. If anyone could explain with an example.

Comment: It might be easiest to grab a debugger, make a piece of code using this function, and stepping through line by line observing the variables and what’s happening.

Comment: For something like that, I'd make a small sample app and run it with a few different test cases; seeing it in action might shed some light.

Comment: It appears to be grabbing the largest item in the array?

Comment: If `n` is 1, return the first element, otherwise let `x` be  result of `fun` with the lesser `n`. When we get through the whole array in this way (right to left) up to the `1`th element, if `x` is bigger than the previous element, the `0`th element, return `x`, return the previous element otherwise. It will traverse the whole array, comparing adjacent elements and percolating the biggest value up to the final return. But you should forget all that and use the top most comment.

Comment: I got bored. Try this out and see if it makes more sense to you. http://cpp.sh/3aoqt

Answer (score 4):

It's the following recurrence relation

- The largest element of an array of size 1 is the first (and last!) element.
- The largest element of an array of size > 1 is the larger of

  - The largest element of a subarray not including the last element
  - The last element

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very concrete example.

Assume the we have the array `int v[] = {1,3,2}`, and look at `fun(v, 3)`.

Substitute those values in the body of the function and you get

```
  int x;
  if(3 == 1)
    return v[0];
  else
    x = fun(v, 3 - 1);  —> Can't continue without this value
  if(x > v[3 - 1])
    return x;
  else
    return v[3 - 1];
```

The first condition is false, so we need to determine `fun(v, 2)`.

Substituting again, this is

```
  int x;
  if(2 == 1)
    return v[0];
  else
    x = fun(v, 2 - 1); —> Can't continue without this value
  if(x > v[2 - 1])
    return x;
  else
    return v[2 - 1];
```

The first condition is still false, so we need to determine `fun(v, 1)`.

This is

```
  int x;
  if(1 == 1)
    return v[0];
  else
    x = fun(v, 1 - 1);
  if(x > v[1 - 1])
    return x;
  else
    return v[1 - 1];
```

Now the first condition is true, so we return `v[0]`, which is 1, and continue with the interrupted `fun(v, 2)`:

```
  int x;
  if(2 == 1)
    return v[0];
  else
    x = 1;  <— continue here
  if(x > v[2 - 1])
    return x;
  else
    return v[2 - 1];
```

Now, `x > v[1]` is clearly false, so we return `v[1]`, which is 3, to `fun(v, 3)`:

```
  int x;
  if(3 == 1)
    return v[0];
  else
    x = 3;    <— continue here
  if(x > v[3 - 1])
    return x;
  else
    return v[3 - 1];
```

And since `3 > v[2]`, we return 3.

A shorter variant of the same function is

```
int fun(int a[], int n)
{
   return n == 1 ? a[0] : max(a[n-1], fun(a, n-1));
}
```